# Disable javascript from scrolling the page in fiefox

Tags: firefox, javascript

I'm required to use a website for school that scrolls the page whenever you click an inputbox. Is there a way to disable JS from scrolling the page?

I've found the section of JS that does the scrolling.

```
  // Automatically scroll to inputs when they gain focus. Do not do this for Partner Chat, where there is only one input.
  $('#activity_shell').find('input').each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('type') == 'text') {
      $(this).focus(function(){ $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: ($(this).offset().top) - 200}, 200); });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to open the developer tools. Then run the following code in the console:

```
window.scrollTo = window.scrollBy = window.scroll = function() {};
```

This replaces all JavaScript functions that can be used for scrolling with a new function that does nothing.

---

Since you now posted the code there is a much easier way - simply unbind the focus event that triggers the scrolling:

```
$('#activity_shell input:text').unbind('focus');
```

Comment: Hmm, that didn't work.

Comment: I added the section of JS that does the scrolling.

Comment: Ah.. it modifies the `scrollTop` property directly.. that makes it tricky.